# Function in Flask returning empty result, whereas the same function is working as expected in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, flask-restful

I am new to using Flask and trying to take string input and redirecting it to another page to display the results of transforming the string. The flow looked something like this:

```
@app.route('/querystring', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def querystring():
    if request.method == "POST":
        frag_string = request.form['fname']
        return redirect(url_for("fragments", frg=frag_string))
    else:
        return render_template("enter_text.html")

@app.route("/<frg>")
def fragments(frg):
    output = set()
    strL = frg.split()
    output=assemble(strL)
    return f"<h1>{frg}</h1>"

def assemble(str_list, min = 3, max = 15):

    if len(str_list) < 2:
        return set(str_list)
    output = set()

    string = str_list.pop()

    for i , candidate in enumerate(str_list):
        matches = set()
        if candidate in string:
            matches.add(string)
        elif string in candidate:
            matches.add(candidate)
        for n in range(min, max+1):
            if candidate[:n] == string[-n:]:
                matches.add(string + candidate[n:])
            if candidate[-n:] == string[:n]:
                matches.add(candidate[:-n] + string)

        for match in matches:
            output.update(assemble(str_list[:i] + str_list[i + 1:] + [match]))

    output_list = list(output)
    print(output_list, file=sys.stderr)

    return output
```

When I try to print the output returned from **assemble** in Jupyter Notebook, it's giving expected results, but in Flask, it's returning an empty set. Is there a mistake related to calling the helper function **assemble**? Kindly help!

Comment: indentation is wrong, and the function only has a comment, it is not easy to work with :)

Comment: I have the indentation correct in my logic. And also, the logic is bit long for me to post here. But the logic is working fine in my jupyter notebook.